# 401 (Unauthorized) Laravel API VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-sanctum

im using laravel 9 and vue js 3 composition API, i always get error 401 when i want to get login user data/ authenticated user, i have tried to find a way and use all the ways, from config settings, etc, i hope anyone can help me because its my first time using laravel sanctum

this is my vue login code, i trying to get the login user data, but i always get 401 Unauthorized

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  isLoggingIn.value = true;

  try {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
    const { data } = await repository.login(credentials);
    if (data) {
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", data.access_token);
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.user));
      let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/profile");
      console.log(response.data);
      router.replace({ name: "restos" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  isLoggingIn.value = false;
};
```

this is my axios code

```
const client = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VUE_APP_API_URL || "http://localhost:8000",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    },
  });
```

my api routes

```
Route::post('/auth/login', [AuthenticationController::class, 'login'])->name('login');

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/auth/profile', [AuthenticationController::class, 'profile'])->name('auth.profile');
});
```

my Kernel.php

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

my cors.php

```
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

and then my .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

i want to get data user login/authenticated user but always get 401 Unauthorized ,thx you so much for the help im very confused about this

Answer (score 0):

This my project last week, maybe can help u.

add this to User Model :

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory,HasApiTokens;

    protected $guarded = []; // like $fillable=[all]
}
```

Route :

```
Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function(){
        Route::post('/auth/signin','signin');
        Route::post('/auth/signup','signup');
    });
```

Controller :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function signin(Request $request){

        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        
        $user = User::whereEmail($credentials['email'])->first();
        
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'login success',
                // send token to front-end
                'token' => $user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken
            ], 200);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'wrong email or password'
        ], 500);
    }

    public function signup(Request $request){

        $request = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required | email | string',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        User::create([
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($request['password'])
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'registration success',
        ], 201);

    }
}
```

and finally :

in my preferences i make a folder lib and create axiosClient.js which contain :

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const axiosClient = axios.create({
    withCredentials:true,
    baseURL:'http://localhost:8000'
})

export const setTokenCSRF = (token) => axios.defaults.headers.common = `Bearer ${token}`
```

and import axiosClient.js in your front end and use setTokenCSRF function to set header axios with token csrf from backend and this token automatically  use in every request.

this token is save in database in table personal_access_token.

and use should learn about csrf token works.
sorry for my english bad.